# PDO search data base to display search result help getting started

Tags: database, search, pdo, web

still learning PHP and struggling im working on a web base reception guested Sign in website for in house use. managers will send reception information about clients or people coming for interviews in a email. recpetion will then add the guest to the website data base ready for the day him or her sign in.

i am stuck on setting up a page where reception can search a date so they know how many guest are coming in that day i am using PDO.
Any help would be amazing.

Many Thanks

```
?php include('connect2.php'); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>



<body>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index.php</title>
</head>
<?php
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM visitors");

    foreach($result as $row) 
    {
        echo $row['firstname'] . "<br>";    
        echo $row['date'] . "<br>"; 
    }




?>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

would like to use a text box to search for certen dates so we can see what we have booked for the next day

Comment: show the code u have

Answer (score 0):

And query should be like

> select * from visitors where date =" $_post ['search ']";